# How to make java only print one message with if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

So im trying to make a program that asks two questions for school. The problem im having is java keeps printing more than one message when I only want one. Is `any`one able to tell me how to do it right? Here is the code:

```
  if (answer1.equals("inside") ||
     answer1.equals("outside") ||
     answer1.equals("both") ) 
     System.out.println("Question 2) Is it a living thing?(yes/no)");
     answer2 = keyboard.next();

  if (answer2.equals("yes") ) 
     System.out.println("Then what else could you be thinking of besides a houseplant?!");

  if (answer2.equals("no") ) 
     System.out.println("Then what else could you be thinking of besides a shower curtain?!");

  if (answer2.equals("yes") ) 
     System.out.println("Then what else could you be thinking of besides a bison?!");

  if (answer2.equals("no") ) 
     System.out.println("Then what else could you be thinking of besides a billboard?!");

  if (answer2.equals("yes") ) 
     System.out.println("Then what else could you be thinking of besides a dog?!");

  if (answer2.equals("no") ) 
     System.out.println("Then what else could you be thinking of besides a cell phone?!");
  }
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you're always checking the _same_ conditions. What exactly do you want to do here?

Comment: what im trying to do is make each statement print a different answer and I dont really know how to do it without using else, else if, or nested if statements(thats part of the assignment)

Comment: `answer2` is always compared to `"yes"` or `"no"`, so if that was true before, it'll remain true, as the variable didn't change value. What is the condition for printing the different answers?

Comment: So are you trying to print a different answer to the console on successive calls? So for instance the first time should print one of the first statements depending on yes or no, (housplant / shower curtain). Then the next should use the choices of (bison / billboard), etc.... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement to accomplish this without using if/else statements. However, you cannot check for "yes" and "no" in multiple if statements without printing out multiple messages as you did in your question.

Create the switch with the parameter set to answer2.toUpperCase() so that each answer will work properly ignoring capitalization.

A switch will execute everything within a case if the case is equal to the parameter. To end each case add "break;" at the end.

```
switch(answer2.toUpperCase()) {

case "YES":

System.out.println("What else could you be thinking of besides a houseplant?!");

break;

case "NO":

System.out.println("Then what else could you be thinking of besides a shower curtain?!");

break;

//And add the rest here

}
```

Comment: One suggestion I do have is if you are trying to randomize which message is printed if answer2 is yes, you might want to use Math.random() to randomly select a response.

Answer (score 0):

using only if statements to check something.

logic (NOTE: not exact code, only logic):

```
//may use a while loop asking the question until a desired answer
System.out.println("(Question 1) Is it a living thing?(yes/no)");
String answerOne = //get user input;
System.out.println("(Question 2) Is it a dead thing?(yes/no)");
String answerTwo = //get user input;

if (answerOne.equals("yes") && answerTwo.equals("no") ) {
    System.out.println("it is a living thing!");
}
if (answerOne.equals("no") && answerTwo.equals("yes") ) {
    System.out.println("its DEAD!");
}
```

Comment: According to his comment under the question, part of the assignment is to not use if else/else or nested if statements.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned this in the question itself, but part of the assignment is to only use if statements with compound conditions

Comment: If I understand what you're looking to do correctly, have you tried using an `if (answer2.equals("xx") && answer1.equals("yy"))`?

Comment: I actually have never heard of doing that before. That seems like it might work. Thank you!

Comment: i have updated my answer. this might be what you're looking for